# Rails One-To-Many Nested Form - Error using controller show action to view posted form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to create a posting form to post a url & some text. The nested form submits without an error but I can't display the subsequent content of that form in my show action controller.

Post Model

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :texts
  has_many :urls 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts, :urls 
 end
```

Text Model

```
 class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post 
 end
```

Url Model

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

Post Controller

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
      @posts = Post.all 
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @texts = @post.texts 
   @urls = @post.urls 
 end 

 def new
  @post = Post.new 
 end 

 def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params) 
   if @post.save 
    redirect_to @post
   else 
    render 'new'
 end 
 end

   private 
   def post_params 
    params.require(:post).permit(:texts_attributes => [:textattr], :urls_attributes => [:urlattr])
   end
```

show.html.erb

```
  <%= @text.textattr %> 
  <%= @url.urlattr %>
```

Database Schema

```
       create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.datetime "created_at", null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
       end

      create_table "texts", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.text     "textattr"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.integer  "post_id"
      end

      add_index "texts", ["post_id"], name: "index_texts_on_post_id"

      create_table "urls", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "urlattr"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.integer  "post_id"
     end

     add_index "urls", ["post_id"], name: "index_urls_on_post_id"

     end
```

Error message after I press submit on the form
!(http://imgur.com/dzdss5z)

Your help would be amazing - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `@text` and `@url` variables are never set in the controller's show action, so they are nil. Hence, there is an error when you try to call those attributes from them in the view.

You have set the `@texts` and `@urls` variables, so you can do something like this:

```
<% @texts.each do |text| %>
  <%= text.textattr %>
<% end %>

<% @urls.each do |url| %>
  <%= url.urlattr %>
<% end %>
```